# How to access elements of an array of function pointers passed to a function by a void pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm trying to pass an array of function pointers to a function by a void pointer. I cannot figure how to access the elements of the array inside the function they are passed to.

Example 1 - Pass regular array via void pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(void* ptr)
{
    int* arr = ptr;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr_nums[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    function((void*)arr_nums);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
`1 2 3 4 5`

Example 2 - Pass functions via void pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return (a - b);
}

int mult(int a, int b)
{
    return (a * b);
}

int divide(int a, int b)
{
    return (a / b);
}

int function(void *ptr)
{
    return ((int(*)(int, int))ptr)(4, 2);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n, function((void*)add));
    printf("%d\n, function((void*)sub));
    printf("%d\n, function((void*)mult));
    printf("%d\n, function((void*)divide));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
6
2
8
2
```

Example 3 - Change add, sub, mult and divide to be a function pointer array:

```
...

int main()
{
    int (* fp_arr[4])(int, int) = { add, sub, mult, divide };
    
    printf("%d\n", function((void*)fp_arr[0]));
    printf("%d\n", function((void*)fp_arr[1]));
    printf("%d\n", function((void*)fp_arr[2]));
    printf("%d\n", function((void*)fp_arr[3]));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
6
2
8
2
```

Problem - Trying to send the whole function pointer array and access the elements inside function:

```
...
int function(void *ptr)
{
    return ((int(*)(int, int))ptr)(4, 2); <--- How to say something like ptr[2], would call mult
}

int main()
{
    int (* fp_arr[4])(int, int) = { add, sub, mult, divide };
    
    printf("%d\n", function((void*)fp_arr));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I left out some details as I was trying to only outline the problem itself, the function I am passing the function pointer array to is from a graphics library and therefore I cannot change the parameter type from void* to something else. Although I do agree with making a typedef'd alias. The library itself is LVGL, but essentially I add a callback function to an object that is triggered on an event with some user data.

i.e - `lv_obj_add_event_cb(obj, callback_fn, my_event_trigger, user_data);`
Where user data would be my function pointer array.
Later when "my_event_trigger" happens on "obj" callback_fn will be called.
Inside the callback function I can access the user data through a function that returns a void pointer like so:

```
void callback_fn(lv_event_t* e)
{
    lv_event_get_user_data(e); // would return a pointer to my data

    // what I want would be something like
    fp_arr[state]; // where it would call a different function depending on the state of the GUI
}
```

Therefore unfortunately I cannot change the type from a void*, but I still don't know how to reference it in such a way that I can access the elements.

Comment: My recommendation is to not use `void *` for the arrays, use the actual type. And for the function pointers, create a type-alias like `typedef int (*function_pointer)(int, int);` and use it like `function_pointer fp_arr[4] = { ... };`

Comment: Note that examples 2 and 3 are not guaranteed to work. A pointer to `void` can be converted to or from a pointer to any *object* type, but functions are not objects. (But note that a pointer to a *function* of some type can be converted to a pointer to a function of a different type and back again, and compare equal to the original pointer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing `*` in the cast in your example, `ptr` is a pointer to an array of function pointers:

```
int function(void *ptr)
{
    return ((int(**)(int, int))ptr)[2](4, 2);
}

int main()
{
    int (*fp_arr[4])(int, int) = { add, sub, mult, divide };
    
    printf("%d\n", function(fp_arr));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that function pointers cannot be portably cast as data pointers and vice versa, so `function((void *)fp_arr[0])` and `function((void*)add)` are not portable, as well as `((int(*)(int, int))ptr)(4, 2)` in examples 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4):

Forget about using things like `return ((int(*)(int, int))ptr)(4, 2);`, that's a huge waste of everyone's time and sanity. Always use `typedef`.

- This is a function `void func (void)`.
- This is a typedef for a function `typedef void func_t (void);`
- This is a function pointer to that function type `func_t* f`.
- This is an array of function pointers: `func_t* f [n]`.

Thus:

```
void some_func (size_t n, func_t* f[n]);
```

(Optionally use `func_t* const array[3]` since you probably don't want to reassign these in run-time.)

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void func_t (void);

void blip (void) {puts(__func__);}
void blop (void) {puts(__func__);}
void blup (void) {puts(__func__);}

void some_func (size_t n, func_t* const f[n])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    f[i]();
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  func_t* const array[3] = { blip, blop, blup };
  some_func(3, array);
}
```